# Add wordpress to only one domain in shared hosting with multiple domains

Tags: hosting, shared-hosting

I got a shared hosting plan with namecheap in which I'm hosting multiple domains. I want to use only one of this domains with wordpress. Can I just install Softaculous Wordpress on my cPanel with any worries. If yes, how can link the domain I want to wordpress?
Will the other domains be affected by wordpress installation?

Comment: This is something you need to ask your host.

Comment: I thought someone has tried this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so from my experience as a WordPress developer, the only downside of the shared hosting is that that's all you got ( in terms of memory ). so if you install [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/download/) from the official site and then upload it to the correct path ( let's say you have bought 3 domains: marinario.ko, marinario.com, marinario.it and the primary domain is marinario.com then inside public_html you can upload the zip of WordPress, if you want to create with WordPress one of the other domain then you have to upload it to public_html/marinario.ko lets say. then you can unzip it and move all the files directly to the folder. then you have to create a DB with a user. you can go then to marinario.com ( if you have uploaded it to public_html ) and enter all the data it wants. if you have any problem with hhtps you can add a redirect rule inside cPanel.
I hope I have helped you :)

Comment: Thanks it helped me!

Comment: nice !!!!! feeling powerful over here

Comment: I bet you are! :D